# React-chartjs-2: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to implement chartjs using react-chartjs-2 but encountered the following error. I am using the following versions:

```
"chart.js": "^4.1.2",
"react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
```

I even tried to downgrade one version but without any luck. I have

```
"type": "module",
```

in package.json and I am trying to use the library with the following imports:

```
import {
      Chart as ChartJS,
      CategoryScale,
      LinearScale,
      BarElement,
      Title,
      Tooltip,
      Legend,
    } from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    BarElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
  );

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart',
      },
    },
  };

  const labels = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
  ];

  const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: labels.map(() =>
          faker.datatype.number({ min: 0, max: 1000 })
        ),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: labels.map(() =>
          faker.datatype.number({ min: 0, max: 1000 })
        ),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
      },
    ],
  };
```

and the following component part of my larger component.

```
  <Bar options={options} data={data} />
```

I tried different ways to import the library but is still not working. Anyone has any clue why? Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Current error displayed by react]

Could it be something with webpack or what else?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there were some linting issues that messed up the library. I added eslint to the project and now everything works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue when using react script version of 3.1.1 when upgraded to version 5 this issue gets resolved.